# Can’t extend GParted partition with unallocated space

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, gparted

I am trying to resize my /dev/sda5

[Partitions view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74mal.jpg)

However I am unable to expand it.
I am on a VirtualBox with Ubuntu on it and I have followed :
https://www.howtogeek.com/124622/how-to-enlarge-a-virtual-machines-disk-in-virtualbox-or-vmware/

- I have resized my Ubuntu.vdi in virtualbox
- I have used the command line :

> VBoxManage modifymedium disk “C:\Users\Flo\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu 20.04\Ubuntu 20.04.vdi” --resize 81920

Once GParted is booted, I can't enlarge my partition

[VirtualBox configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjzuo.jpg)

How can I extend sda5 ?
Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: /dev/sda5 is inside /dev/sda2. You need to expand sda2 first, then you will be able to expand sda5. You cannot do this without booting into a live environment. Download the GParted iso, add a virtual CD drive if you don’t have one, insert the iso in the CD drive and boot it. Then resize as above

Comment: @PonJar Thank you it worked !